# Error with propel-generate-crud in Symfony 1.0

Tags: php, command-line, symfony1, crud

When I try to generate a CRUD test for a new project I am getting a PHP Warning and a Fatal Error.

The errors relate to files that it cannot find, however, I have checked and the files are definitely there.

The error text is 'require_once(lib/model/map/QuestionMapBuilder.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in c:\webroot\askeet\lib\model\om\BaseQuestionPeer.php on line 547'

What details of my project should I check?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down the issue. In my PHP.ini files, they were setup wit the default UNIX file path settings.

Weirdly nothing had ever been broken by this incorrect configuration. Plus, everything in Symfony had worked up until now.

I have switched to Windows style file_path and all is well again.

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with your include path.

Check it, the require_once() call is looking for `lib/model/map/QuestionMapBuilder.php`

But your include_path is `C:\webroot\askeet\lib`

Which, when resolved together into a full path, would look like this

```
C:\webroot\askeet\lib\lib\model\map\QuestionMapBuilder.php
```

So, I *think* your solution is to add `C:\webroot\askeet` to your include path.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating crud for the **Question** model class but it doesn't seem to exist. Documentation on using the [crud generator](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/04-Propel-Integration#chapter_04_the_crud_generator)

First you must use the [schema.yml file](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/04-Propel-Integration) to define your database, and run

```
./symfony propel:build-model
```

to generate your model files. (this will generate lib\model\map\QuestionMapBuilder.php)